# Jquery Css Move Div Up Down into another Div on Scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

hi i want to scroll small button inside each division when the division are viable or in view port. i tried using `scrollTop()` but its scrolling all div

i want to create similar effect they are using on download button

```
https://www.template.net/web-templates/bootstrap/bootstrap-gallery-template/
```

here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var el = $('.spicbo');
var elpos_original = el.offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var elpos = el.offset().top;
    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
    var finaldestination = windowpos;
    if(windowpos<elpos_original) {
        finaldestination = elpos_original;
        el.stop().css({'top':5});
    } else {
        el.stop().animate({'top':finaldestination-elpos_original+10},400);
    }
});
```

thank you in advance

Comment: based on what I understand, you want to be able to move a button up/down when you hover your mouse over another element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a working example based on what I seen in the prototype webpage you have provided in [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/ZQNwKo). In this example, when mouse pointer moves inside of `container` div, `button` moves smoothly around with the pointer.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <button type="submit">download</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
   position: relative;
   margin-top: 20px;
   width: 300px;
   height: 100px;
   background: #ccc;
 }

 button {
   position: absolute;
   opacity: 0;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   margin: 5px;
   transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
 }
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var currentMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };

   $(".container").mousemove(function(event) {
     if ((event.pageY + $("button").outerHeight(true) - 20) < $(".container").height()) {
         currentMousePos.y = event.pageY - 20;
      }

      $("button").css({opacity:1});
      $("button").stop(true,true).animate({
          top: currentMousePos.y
      }, 200)
   });

   $(".container").mouseleave(function() {
     $("button").css({opacity:0});
   });
```

});

In the `mousemove` event, we track mouse pointer when it is inside of `container` div. If the mouse pointer is down the div so that it pushes the button out of the div, we do not update `currentMousePos.y` so that `button` will always stay inside of `container`. Then we change the `opacity` to 1 and use `animate` to move the button around accordingly. On the `mouseleave` event, we return `button` to invisible state.